# Java client and c server not getting connected

Tags: java, c, sockets

My program has got a java gui part which takes username and password and concantenates them into one. Then it is sent to server through socket.The C server reads the string and checks with the users stored in a file(User_File). Then it returns the type of user.. that is whether admin or user.. The string that is sent over socket is not read over there.But the message before that telling that the connection is created is printed in server.. Please look into this..

Java client

```
private void loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) throws ClassNotFoundException  {//GEN-FIRST:event_loginActionPerformed
// TODO add your handling code here:
String user=uname.getText();
String pwd=pass.getText();
if(user.equals("")||pwd.equals(""))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fields cannot be empty");
else
{

    user = user.concat("$");
      user = user.concat(pwd);
      user = user.concat("$");
      System.out.println("User: "+user);
   /*   
      /** Define a host server */
  try
  {
      String host = "localhost";
      /** Define a port */
      int port = 35685;

      StringBuffer instr = new StringBuffer();
      String TimeStamp;
      System.out.println("SocketClient initialized");



        /** Obtain an address object of the server */
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);


        Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);




        System.out.println("SocketClient is initialized");


            PrintWriter dout = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), true);

             ObjectInputStream din = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

             dout.println(user);



             String str = din.readLine();


             System.out.println("Read >"+str+"<");


                    if(str.equals("User"))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successull login");
                        DisplayQuestions us = new DisplayQuestions();
                        us.setVisible(true);
                        this.dispose();

                    }

      }catch(IOException ex){}
}
}//GEN-LAST:event_loginActionPerformed
```

c server:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MYPORT 35685
#define BUFFERSIZE 100

char * readstring(int);
int authenticate(char *);
int writestring(int, char *);
char * readfile(int);
void sig_handler(int);


int sd; /* Socket for data transfer */

int main(
    int argc,
    char * argv[])
{
    int connfd; /* Active socket */
    int ret;    /* return value of functions */
    int status = 0; /* status of user defined functions */
    char * login; /* Char array to store user name and password */
    char wr_buffer[BUFFERSIZE];   /* Write buffer */
    char buf[BUFFERSIZE];   

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr,  /* server address */
               clientaddr;  /* Client address */
    socklen_t length;   /* Length of client address */

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (0 > sd)
    {
    printf("Socket Creation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Signal handler */
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);

    /* Populating server */

    memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    /* Binding the socket */

    ret = bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
    if (0 > ret)
    {
    printf("Binding Error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Assigning number of clients */

    ret = listen(sd, 5);
    if (0 > ret)
    {
    printf("Listening failure\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for(;;)
    {
    printf("I am waiting for client...\n");
    length = sizeof(clientaddr);
        connfd = accept(sd ,(struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &length);

    if (0 > connfd)
        {
        if (errno == EINTR)
        {
        printf("Interrupted system call\n");
        }
        continue;
    }
        printf("Connfd created\n");
        memset(buf, '\0', BUFFERSIZE);
    printf("Connection from %s\n",inet_ntop(AF_INET, &clientaddr.sin_addr, buf, sizeof(buf)));

        memset(wr_buffer, '\0', BUFFERSIZE);

    /* Reading user name and pass word from the user */

    login = readstring(connfd);

    printf("\nRead: %s", login);

        /* Checking whether user is authenticated or not */

        status = authenticate(login);

    if (0 < status)
    {
        if (1 == status)            /* status 1 for user */
        {
        strcpy(wr_buffer, "User");
        }
        if (2 == status)            /* status 2 for Admin */
        {
        strcpy(wr_buffer, "Admin");
        }

        ret = writestring(connfd, wr_buffer);   /* writing the string to socket */
        if (0 > ret)
        {
        printf("Writing to socket failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Successfully written\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(wr_buffer, "NotUser");   /* Status 0 for non user */
        ret = writestring(connfd, wr_buffer);
        if (0 > ret)
        {
        printf("Writing to socket failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Successfully written\n");
        }
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        ret = close(connfd);
    if (0 > ret)
    {
        printf("error in closing active socket\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        printf("Finished serving one client\n");
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

char * readstring(int sd)
{
    int flag = 0;
    int pointer = 0;
    int bytesread = 0;
    char * buffer;

    buffer = (char*) calloc (sizeof(char), BUFFERSIZE);

    /* Reading string from socket */

    while (0 < (bytesread = read(sd, buffer + pointer, BUFFERSIZE)))
    {
    pointer += bytesread;
        flag = 1;
        if ('*' == buffer[pointer - 1])
    {
        break;
        }
    }
    buffer[pointer - 1] = '\0';     /* Removing * from the string received from client */
    if (0 == flag)          /* Flag 0 for error in reading and 1 for success */
    {
    printf("Error in reading\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return buffer;
}

int authenticate(char * buffer)
{
    int fd;
    int ret = 0;
    int status = 0;
    char * temp;
    char * user;
    char * passwd;
    char * file_buffer;

    fd = open("User_File",O_RDONLY);    /* User_File is file containing the username,passwd and status */
    if (0 > fd)
    {
        printf("Error in opening file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
                    /* buffer is from client having username and passwd concatenated using $ */
    user = strtok(buffer,"$");
    passwd = strtok(NULL, "$");

    file_buffer = readfile(fd);     /* storing file contents in the file_buffer */

    temp = strtok(file_buffer, "$");

    while (NULL != temp)        /* Tokenising file_buffer using $ */
    {
        if (0 == strcmp(temp, user))    /* If token matches with user string */
        {
        temp = strtok(NULL, "$");
        if (0 == strcmp(temp, passwd))  /* Checking for passwd matching */
        {
        temp = strtok(NULL,"$");
        status = atoi(temp);        /* If passwd matches assigning status value to status */
            }
            break;
    }
        temp = strtok(NULL,"$");
    }

    ret = close(fd);
    if (0 > ret)
    {
    printf("Error in closing\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return status;      /* Return status value */
}

char * readfile(int fd)
{
    struct stat sb;
    int size;
    int ret;
    char * buffer;

    fstat(fd, &sb);
    size = sb.st_size;

    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * (size + 1));

    ret = read(fd, buffer, (size + 1));     /* storing contents of file into buffer */
    if (0 > ret)
    {
    printf("Reading error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    buffer[size] = '\0';
    return buffer;
}

int writestring(
        int sd, 
        char * buffer)
{
    int byteswritten = 0;
    int pointer = 0;
    int length;

    strcat(buffer, "*");    /* Append msg to be sent with '*' */
    length = strlen(buffer);

    while (pointer < length)
    {
    byteswritten = write(sd,buffer + pointer, length - pointer);    /* writing to socket */
    if (0 > byteswritten)
    {
        printf("error in writing to socket\n");
        return 0;
    }
        pointer += byteswritten;
    }
    return 1;
}

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    int ret;
    if (SIGINT  == sig)
    {
    printf("Exiting server \nCtrl + C Pressed\n");
        ret = close(sd);
        if (0 > ret)
    {
        printf("Error in closing \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    }
}
```

User_File:

```
user1$abc123$1$
user2$def123$1$ /* 1 for user */
user3$abg123$2$ /* 2 for admin */
```

Comment: Where and when does the Java client write the `'*'`?

Comment: thanku.. i appended the * after appending the $ atlast.. But still it is not working

Comment: Same question rephrased: do you really want `readstring()` to loop forever (as appears to be happening) if the client doesn't put a '*' in its request?

Comment: Probably you still use println to send. Doesn't that append a newline after the final character? In which case, '*' is still not the last character, putting readline() into the infinite loop again.

Comment: sir,i didn't get you.. * is inserted so that readstring doesnot loop forever...

Comment: Compile the C part with symbols using option `-g` and then run the server in gdb to observer, trace and inspect what is going on.

Comment: When sending via `println` the last character sent is a `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace '*' in readline() with '\n'.